# Axios GET returning NULL when I just did POST with success

Tags: api, vue.js, post, get, axios

This is my code for axios post,

```
var config = { headers: {  
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
             }
      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
      },config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

But when I do this,

```
axios
      .get('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
      .then(response => console.log(response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

I get response data as null. I'm not able to POST data through axios. I don't know why this is happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are your POST and GET requests related to each other?

Comment: Is there any erros in the console after the POST request?

Comment: no there aren't any errors it is showing status 200 and OK. @Anatoly

Comment: Check your backend code: either POST does not save your information or your GET incorrectly populates it from a storage